# Proper spark plug gap

Tags: engine, ford, sparkplugs, ranger

What is the gap for a 98 ranger 3.0? The stickers under hood are gone and there is no book in glove box. I just bought this truck and have nothing to go on.

Comment: Since most engines tolerate different type of spark plugs a type code would be interesting. Most producers publish the values on their website..

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I think it would be easier to buy new clean plugs specific to your vehicle and engine, and not hassle with trying to regap.  That practice went out with setting point dwell and the big "Defunct Knowledge Ban" of 'aught 3...

Answer (score 2):

According to [this website](https://www.ford-trucks.com/forums/125651-3-0l-plug-gaps.html), the gap as stated in the manual should be .042 - .046".